# Spring Controller: Passing Url As Parameter 404 Error

Tags: java, spring, model-view-controller

My controller attaches a question mark at the end of a string. It works great for every types of string.

```
https://www.mywebsite.com/attachQuestionmark/33 returns 33?
https://www.mywebsite.com/attachQuestionmark/hello returns hello?
```

However it returns not found error for urls such as https:://www.test.com.

https://www.mywebsite.com/attachQuestionmark/https:://www.test.com returns 404 error.

Is there any way to pass a full url to spring mvc controller?

```
@RequestMapping(
            value = MyUrlBuilder.API_CREATIVE_CREATE + "/attachQuestionmark/{string}",
            method = RequestMethod.GET,
            produces = MediaType.ALL_VALUE)
    @ResponseBody
    @PMET
    public static String attachQustionmark(@PathVariable("url") String value)
    {
        return value + "?";
    }
```

Comment: why? I am just curious what is the use case of this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [URL-encoding](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLEncoder.html) the path variable, eg:

https://www.mywebsite.com/attachQuestionmark/https%3A%3A%2F%2Fwww.test.com

Because otherwise the / inside the variable will be interpreted as another path